How do I obtain the parsed tz offset when parsing tz-aware strings with Polars?
When using Polars to parsing datetime strings with offset information, the output is always in UTC:
pl.Series(['2020-01-01T01:00+10:00']).str.to_datetime()

shape: (1,)
Series: '' [datetime[μs, UTC]]
[
        2019-12-31 15:00:00 UTC
]

I assume the reason for this is it's impossible to represent a series with a non-constant timezone, so this behaviour is the only sane way to deal with inputs like [+1, +2, +3] (of which DST changes are an example).
It's all well and good that polars doesn't want to get into making fuzzy guesses, but how do I get the "+10:00" safely out to deal with this myself? (or the [+1, +2, +3] in harder cases.) chrono is successfully parsing it out as an offset, how can I get it as a pl.Duration column or something without having to hand-roll offset parsing from scratch myself?

The only option currently available would be to use map_elements and do the parsing in Python:
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

s = pl.Series(['2020-01-01T01:00+10:00', '2024-03-02T03:12-14:00'])
def func(row):
    parsed = datetime.strptime(row, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z')
    return parsed.tzinfo.utcoffset(parsed)

s.map_elements(func, return_dtype=pl.Duration)

shape: (2,)
Series: '' [duration[μs]]
[
        10h
        -14h
]

